# CoreData not storing data across multiple iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to build an iOS application using Objective C.

Where say some user is logged into my App as `UserName A` and they want to invite for a particular task, another user of my App ,`B` using their `FirstName/LastName/Phone Number`.

I am using `Coredata` to store the user credentials when they register.

The issue is : This works fine when I register both A and B from the same iOS device but NOT when I register `A` from iOS device 1 and `B` from iOS device2.

`Coredata` seems to store only the user data in the local device.

**How can I ensure my app works for all users logged in form any iOS device ?**

Comment: As the comment below states CoreData does not automatically do this for you. What kind of information are you trying to store and synch? There are lots of 3rd party solutions available but most of them will be focused around product eg instant chat

Answer (score 2):

Core Data does not upload data to any server or synchronize data across devices. It's designed as a local-only data store. You can turn on iCloud syncing in Core Data, but this has been deprecated as of iOS 10.

If you want your app data to be available across multiple devices, you'll need to write some code to do that. Apple provides CloudKit, and there are many third party solutions. But you can't just tell Core Data to sync data, because Core Data doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom! That clarifies things a little bit. I just started reading about CloudKit and it looks like it will work in my case only when the users "A" and "B" of my App share the same cloud which is not always true, Please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Apple recently introduced a sharing option for CloudKit that doesn't have this requirement-- see the [WWDC 2016 video on the topic](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226/).